# Confused about the explanation of the difference between "expence" and "expense"

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, difference, word-difference

I've checked [WikiDiff](https://wikidiff.com/expence/expense) for the difference between *expence* and *expense* wanting to verify that it's corresponding to *licence* (the object or permission to do something) and *license* (the act of issuing said object or establishing/accreditation of said permission).

However, the explanation hit me with whoosh big time. I simply can't determine what's being said. I can't exclude error in the text, of course, but being humble I want to investigate if it might be me.

> As nouns the difference between **expense** and **expence** is that **expense** is a spending or consuming often specifically an act of disbursing or spending funds while **expence** is.

Also, on top of that, it got me confused and uncertain about the actual difference so +1 to whoever answers that too.

Comment: The sentence you quoted is incomplete. It cuts off abruptly without finishing. *". . .while expence is"* [**what**?] However, that's how it's written on the site itself. Also, the sentence as a whole is very awkard. That alone brings WikiDiff as a good source of information into question. You'd do far better to use one of the major dictionaries.

Comment: @JasonBassford You just confirmed my impression. I was afraid that not being NSE, I somehow miss the target of the last part. Something along the lines of *my dog isn't angry, while yours is*. In my language, it's very awkward but in English it flies just fine.

Comment: In *that* phrase, it's okay. Because it's contrasting something that isn't with something that is. But in the quoted sentence, there's nothing to understand, even by omission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Expence" is an obsolete spelling of "expense" (like *whiche* and *laste* and many, many others) and should not be used.  You might see "expence" in archaic documents, but in modern documents it's simply a spelling mistake.

Example from ["The Expence of University Education Reduced: In a Letter to A. B. Fellow E.C." (1733)](https://books.google.com/books?id=oI9bAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22expence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8q-THts3hAhVpwVQKHUDUB5UQ6AEIPjAD#v=onepage&q=%22expence%22&f=false)

> The **Expence** requiſite to Education has Limits, and may be known to a certainty within a trifle. The **Expence** occaſion'd by Idleneſs, or Humour, or Vanity, or Luxury, or Affected Hoſpitality is Infinite, or, at leaſt, hath no other.

Note the [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) (ſ) which is pronounced like "s", as well as the capitalization of certain nouns, both of which no longer appear in modern English.

Comment: OK, technically speaking, +1 for the reassurance of how to spell it. However, the main question is about WikiDiff. Is is plain, butt-ugly wrong? I'm evaluating it a  a future source of references so I'd like to know if it's a red flag.

Comment: @KonradViltersten  It seems to me that WikiDiff is not itself a dictionary but instead uses some kind of algorithm to compare different sources.  It seems to do little (if anything) to *verify* those sources, so, while it can be a helpful resource, it's not a reliable tool for primary research.